# Need Help in Python Dictionary Related Task

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a dictionary,

```py
dictionary = {
   'AE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':3 }, 
   'BE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':2 }, 
   'CE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':5 },
}
```

With comprehension in definition, yield the output as,

```py
output = [['AE':'BE':'CE'], 
          ['Applied', 2,4,5],
          ['Programming', 5,3,2]]
```

Comment: "Help" implies effort on your part. Not just doing it for you. Do you have code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```py
dictionary = {
   'AE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':3 }, 
   'BE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':2 }, 
   'CE':{'Applied':4, 'Programming':5 },
}

output = []
dict_keys = list(dictionary.keys())
output.append(dict_keys)

for key in dictionary[dict_keys[0]]:
    value = [dictionary[k][key] for k in dict_keys]
    value.insert(0, key)
    output.append(value)
```

Output:

```py
output = [['AE', 'BE', 'CE'], ['Applied', 4, 4, 4], ['Programming', 3, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir, I was working on it but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Can you get same output using Comprehension?

Comment: Its my pleasure @MuhammadBasitMukhtar, you can use this **list comprehension**: `dict_keys = list(dictionary.keys()); output = [[dictionary[k][key] for k in dictionary.keys()] for key in dictionary[dict_keys[0]]]` , but the output will be: `output = [[4, 4, 4], [3, 2, 5]]`